what is the difference between notEmpty and exists in express-validator
I can't understand what is the difference between exists and notEmpty in express-validator both works the same.


exists() checks if the property is defined in the request.
notEmpty() checks if the property has a value set or not.

In query parameters (for example), you can submit ?key=value while the value may be optional and defaults to an empty string.
If it's empty or "":

notEmpty returns false
exists returns true

If it has a value:

notEmpty returns true
exists returns true

If the key is not there:

notEmpty returns false
exists returns false

Another example:
/query?param&num=5


exists("param") returns true.
exists("otherParam") returns false.
notEmpty("param") returns false.
notEmpty("otherParam") returns false.
exists("num") returns true
notEmpty("num") returns true

You have the same possibilities in Objects (even more...):


const obj = {
  param: undefined,
  notEmpty: null,
  null: 0
};
// similar to exists
console.log("param" in obj, "param in obj"); // true
console.log("toString" in obj, "toString in obj"), // true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("param"), "ownProp"); // true
// it is inherited from the Object.prototype
// and has no own toString() function, so we
// expect false
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("toString"), "ownProp"); // false


// similar to notEmpty
console.log(obj.param === null, "param === null"); // false

// every property, that doesn't exists,
// returns undefined, but the value 
// "undefined" can also be assigned to a
// property
console.log(obj.param === undefined, "param === undef"); // true
console.log(obj.otherParam !== undefined, "otherParam !== undefined"); // false
console.log(obj.otherParam === null, "otherParam === null"); // false
console.log(obj.notEmpty === undefined, "notEmpty === undefined"); // false

// other cases:
// on loosly equal (==), null gets handled equal to undefined 
console.log(obj.param == null, "otherParam == null"); // true
console.log(obj.null == null, "0 == null");
// inside a condition, number 0, empty string,
// null and undefined are threaded like "false"
console.log(obj.null ? true : false, "no comparision"); // false



